# How to show processing form in my main form

Tags: winforms, process, c#-2.0, show

I want to show processing  image in form when my main form is working.

I have created processing form .

I tried it with

```
ProcessingForm obj = new ProcessingForm();

obj.show();

DOSomeStuff();

obj.close();
```

it shows processing form..but some time it becomes not responding...or my gif image stops animating.

How to do that??

Comment: This cannot work.  You have to use a BackgroundWorker to prevent freezing your UI thread.  *Many* threads about it on this web site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BackgroundWorker` class to separate process working under Form Messages processing and Processing your code like `DoSomeStuff()`. If you want know what progress of your `DoSomeStuff()` was done, you can implemend in your background worker this because this class support it.

But if your enviroment is to slow to getting this 2 things processing in realtime, you must give your BackgroundWorker some lowest priority then your image can be working in realtime but your stuff doing longer. *This is not good solution because depends on enviromen.*

Answer (score 0):

I've used [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgressIndicator.aspx?msg=2920189) from CodeProject. It's a "rotating" timer animation similar to that used by Firefox.

Add the dll as a reference to your project and drop the progress indicator on your form.

Set it's initial state to be invisible.

Then when you want to show your processing call:

```
this.progressIndicator.Visible = true;
this.progressIndicator.Start();
```

To remove it when the processing is complete call:

```
this.progressIndicator.Stop();
this.progressIndicator.Visible = false;
```

It uses a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` to control the animation and overrides the `OnPaint` method to draw the image rotating. This is probably as accurate as you would need.

I'm not the author, but I have used this and not had any problems with it slowing the actual processes down appreciably.

However, you will have to put your processing onto another thread - use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, otherwise the UI won't update.

Comment: That won't work either, for the same reason the OP's ProcessingForm doesn't work.  No Tick events when the UI thread doesn't pump the message loop.